# How to give each label on axis its own color?

Tags: python-2.7, charts, data-visualization, bokeh

I want to make graph with Bokeh where each label on axis has it's own color.

```
p.xaxis.major_label_text_color = "red"
```

This sets color for all text labels on axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the current implementation of the axis model. You're welcome to create a feature request on [Bokeh's GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) or to create a custom axis model that you can use instead of the default one. Here's [the relevant part](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/lib/models/axes/axis.ts#L115-L123) in Bokeh source code in case you decide to implement a custom model.